# iPhone6 screen size returns 375 on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

My project has launch images for all iPhones iOS7,iOS8.

Anyway it keeps returning wrong value for the screen width in simulator:

```
   NSLog(@"%f",[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.width);
```

both always are 375.0.

What am i missing ?

Comment: What value are you expecting? The @1x iPhone 6 screen width is 375 pixels wide.

Comment: i expect to get the real value like i always had - 750

Comment: how is that in some projects you get 750 and others 375 ? i need the size not in pixles

Comment: The iPhone always calculates with the "@1x" size. So if you create a view with specific pixels, it has to be 375 and not 750. Check out this: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual screen size of iPhone6 is 750 pixels, but iOS does not return the pixel size in the frame or bounds, but the point size!

If you want to know how many pixels are in a point you have to use `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` .

For iPhone6plus this is even more complicated since it also introduces a 'native scale'. Everything is drawn into a larger image and the reduced down to the 1920x1080 screen that the iPhone 6 actually has. For this you would use `[UIScreen mainScreen].nativeScale` [Careful, native scale is only available on iOS8 and your app will crash if you use it on iOS.]

P.S. If you are not using any splash image (other than -568h@2x), you will get 320x568 for iPhone 6 and 6+.